# Postgres Authentication Fails When Starting Dajngo

Tags: postgresql, django, python3, postgis

I am in the process of restoring my Django development server to another virtual machine. I have set up Django, Postgres, installed the GIS extensions and restored the database.

When I run the server, I get the error below:

> password authentication failed for user "myuser"

With "myuser" I can connect to the Postgres database as that user with the same password specified in "mysettings.py" and create and drop tables so I don't understand why it is not connecting.

My settings.py looks like this:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
    'NAME': 'travel',
    'USER': 'myuser',
    'PASSWORD': 'Passw0rd',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '',
}
```

}

Can someone help? It doesn't make sense to me if I can log on as that user and create / drop tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by creating a new user in postgres and using their credentials in settings.py. I needed to make that user a super user.

The previous user was a local user on the server which was linked to the postgres account so I don't understand why it didn't work in that case. Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without a bit more information, but `''` isn't a valid port number. You should probably use PostgreSQL's default port, 5432.

Comment: I've tried that just and get the same error.

Comment: On other servers I haven't specified a port no. and it's been fine.